# How to remove segment from URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, url-rewriting, codeigniter-2

My URL adress looks like this:

> /blog/topic/6/test

can it be changed like this:

> /blog/topic/test

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.x

Comment: yeah sure :) but please explaing _when_ you want to change to url; do you want the url `/blog/topic/test` to be equivalent to `/blog/topic/6/test` (which sounds a bit odd to me because you can probably not identify the right topic anymore, unless `test` is a unique name), or do you want to just filter out the number after someone already reached the controller by requesting the first version of your url? In that case, depending on the strictness of the syntax of your url, an explode() or a call to a regex function would do

Comment: I just want to hide the id in the url - in this case (6), but it can be another number. Also I use it as a method's parameter and this method uses it.

Comment: well the problem here is that you need the id somehow to designate the right post. So this can only be done if either the string `test` is a unique identifier, so you could do something like `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE topic_slug='test'` or if you have saved the id already in a session. Because php can do alot, but not magically read the user's mind to fetch the desired topic :)

Comment: i assume btw that the number is a topic id which you use to fetch the right topic. If it is just a random number, change your routes ;)

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. :D 
/blog/topic/6/test - blog is the controller, topic is the method, 6 is the id and test is the topic's title. And I just want to remove the id.

Comment: well then, if 'test' is the topic title you have a chance, but then you have to make the title unique, which is most of the times not desirable. Otherwise, to make it look a bit sweeter you can turn them around (title and id).

Comment: Okay, thanks! I was just curious how wordpress succeeded on this.

Comment: well wordpress creates unique slugs; when you have title like `This is my blogpost`, it converts it to `this-is-my-blogpost`, saves it in a unique mysql cell and looks it up when needed. When you have two of the same titles, you could convert the slug, as it's called, to `this-is-my-blogpost-2` or something like that. Think of your own logic for handling that type of situations. But it can be done if you add a new column in your database!

Comment: Thank you again. I will think of something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the 6 is just the GET parameter - you can use POST instead!